# the ways of using zip function to generate the cell location based on the row and column information

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-zip

I created the following dataframe, and would like to identify the cells which are Null,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3},
        {'a':10, 'b': np.NaN, 'c':"" },
         {'a':10, 'b':"" , 'c':np.NaN }]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

     a    b     c
0    1    2     3
1   10   NaN    
2   10         NaN
```

I used the following code, `x1 = np.where(pd.isnull(df))` and get the result like

```
print(x1)
(array([1, 2], dtype=int64), array([1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

However, I want to generate the cell location explicitly for each entry associated with NaN. I use the zip function, but get the following error message

```
print(set(zip(x1)))



 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [41], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 print(set(zip(x1)))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

What are the right ways to generate the location information explicitly based on x1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
null_indices, col_idx = np.where(df.isna())
null_columns = df.columns[col_idx]
```

Output:

```
(array([1, 2], dtype=int64), Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object'))
```

If you want to see it as tuples, you can `zip`:

```
out = list(zip(null_indices, null_columns))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

For your specific code, since `x1` is a tuple of arrays, you need to unpack them inside `zip`, like:

```
out = list(zip(*x1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `stack` then get the `NaN` index

```
df.stack(dropna=False).loc[lambda x : x!=x].index.tolist()
Out[115]: [(1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The solution you posted is pretty interesting. It seems to me that you were using x!=x to identify the NaN cell. Why it can work? Thanks.

Comment: @user785099 by definition np.nan != np.nan, you can test